# How to dynamically change the output from a function based on the arguments passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I am trying to build a function in python that returns back an output depending on the arguments passed by the user.

Given below is the basic function:

```
def report():
    db_conn
    dwh_cursor = conn.cursor()  # set DB Cursor

    ## Query
    dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,class,team,position from students"""))
```

The above function works fine when executed. What I am trying to modify here is when I pass one argument with value only that column should be returned at the output of the function. For example in the below function I pass just two arguments namely name and class and I expect only those two values in the output as shown below:

```
def report(name,class,team,position):
    db_conn
    dwh_cursor = conn.cursor()  # set DB Cursor

    ## Query
    dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,class,team,position from students"""))

report("Scott","High_School","","")

Expected query to be executed:

    ## Query
    dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""select (%s),(%s) from students"""), (name,class))
```

Could anyone guide me as to how to get this specified output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably find it easier to pass in a list of column names to be retrieved.

```
def report(*field_names):
    db_conn
    dwh_cursor = conn.cursor()  # set DB Cursor

    if not field_names:
        field_names = ('name', 'class', 'team', 'position')

    ## Query
    dwh_cursor.execute('select {} from students'.format(', '.join(field_names)))
    ...

report('name', 'class')
```

**Health Warnings**

1. dynamically generating sql based on user input is risky (i.e. if an unknown / untrusted user could set the text which is put into the query then they could substantially alter the queries you're running)
2. if this is a part of a larger application to be supported, you might benefit from an ORM tool (e.g. sqlalchemy) to handle interfacing with the database for you

Comment: thanks for your reply. I see that when I try to execute the above query it just keep processing without any message.. Used the exact same input as you had adviced..